# Android - download files in parallel and enter in DB

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I know (i think so) how to download a file from a given URL. Used HTTP client to download the file and wrapped it in a runnable. I am assuming in order to be able to download multiple files in parallel, I can simply create more instances of the runnable, and add them to an ExecutorService.

I have already created framework to work with the SQLite DB. Used an ASync task to getwritabledatase, and then add some properties related to the file downloaded to the DB.

What I am unable to wrap my head around is how to make sure I can allow a user to download multiple files, and on completing the donwload, add the DB entry, all in an async manner so that user is free to navigate to another activity (dont have to handle a requirement when he logs out)/

Can I initiate an Async task after the httpclient returns with the file, inside my runnable/run()? or is that a bad practice since the runnable is already sipping off 1 thread and then another in form of async task? Any other suggestion?

Unfortunately I cannot use external libraries provided by someone on git/etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I initiate an Async task after the httpclient returns with the file, inside my runnable/run()? or is that a bad practice since the runnable is already sipping off 1 thread and then another in form of async task? Any other suggestion?

Downloading a file and writing an entry to the database are two independent operations. You should not do both within the same `AsyncTask` or `Runnable`. It will work though, but this is a bad architecture, I think.

Usually you have something like a download manager which is a class that has a mentioned executor. You call this download manager from your controller, for example activity or fragment, and once you receive a callback you can initiate a background task that will write data to the database. It can be anything: `AsyncQueryHandler`, `Runnable`, `AsyncTask` etc. Choose a solution that works better for your use case.

> (dont have to handle a requirement when he logs out)/

This is not a problem at all as long as you use a UI-independent component such as `Service`. You don't need to have a UI to download a file and write it to the database.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was bad architecture, but can't think of a better solution. What you suggested, keep 2 separate asynctask, once the 1st one completes, suggesting that files is downloaded, fire off the next one which makes the DB entry. That was my first thought as well.
But then more complexities came in. User can select multiple files to download, (like dropbox saving files offline..?) and while the files are downloading, he can navigate away from that activity (files can be large, I cant force him to stay) in which case, I dont think I will get a call back the 1st operation is comeplete

Comment: That will work too. But keep in mind that AsyncTask is not an android component, it's just a wrapper around thread. So if the system will be running on low memory android will more likely kill your app when it's in background. If this is a concern, use a Service which will increase your app priority.

Comment: wait, little confused. (Memory part aside, thanks for reminding though).
You are saying I can initiate an Async to download, and say, in it's postexecute, fire off another Async to make DB entry? And all this will work, even if user goes away from that activity where this Async was initiated? 
1) Won't the user navigation away from activity cause issues? 
2) I suppose answer to this is yes, but still...I can fire off 5 instance of Async task to simultaneously download 5 files?

Comment: 1) If you use an AsyncTask, you attach it to an Android component (I mean start it from somewhere). If you do this from an Activity then yes, it will be attached to the UI and you will have problems in this case. Instead, you can start it from a Service which works in a background. In this case user can navigate across the app with no issue. 2) You can fire off as many as you want. If you want to run 5 downloads in parallel make sure you use a pool executor because otherwise it will be sequential: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR